# Conditional Distribution is a Binomial

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I've been working on some problems related to multivariate distributions in my
independent studies, and I came across one that I am feeling mixed about.
Consider $X \sim Poisson(\lambda_x) \wedge Y \sim Poisson(\lambda_y),$ and
consider $W = X + Y.$ I want to figure out the conditional distribution of $X$
given $W = w.$ I have a feeling that I should go about proving the
$W \sim Poisson(\lambda_x + \lambda_y)$, but for now I will assume this
(if anyone has any suggestions on how to prove that one, I'd like some help
on that too).

We see that
$$P(X = c | W = w) = \frac{P(X = c \wedge W = w)}{P(W = w)}
= \frac{P(Y = w - c)}{P(W = w)}$$
$$=\frac{(\lambda_y)^{w-c} e^{-\lambda_y}\frac{1}{(w-c)!}}{
        (\lambda_x + \lambda_y)^{w} e^{-(\lambda_x+\lambda_y)} \frac{1}{w!}}.$$

I thought this would be enough, but my professor told me that I should find
some way to manipulate this into a binomial distribution. Any recommendations on
where to simplify this? I am having some difficulties figuring this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a bit.
$$\begin{align}P(X = c \mid W = w) ~=~& \frac{P(X = c \wedge W = w)}{P(W = w)}
\\~=~& \frac{P(Y = w - c)~\color{crimson}{P(X=c)}}{P(W = w)}\\~=~& \frac{(\lambda_y)^{w-c} e^{-\lambda_y}\frac{1}{(w-c)!}~\color{crimson}{(\lambda_x)^c e^{-\lambda_x}\tfrac 1{x!}}}{ (\lambda_x + \lambda_y)^{w} e^{-(\lambda_x+\lambda_y)} \frac{1}{w!}}
\end{align}$$

Now can you obtain the expression for a binomial distribution ?

---

As for the proof that $W$ is a Poisson random variable :> A Poisson random variable is the count of events within an interval when the events each arrive independent of previous events and at a constant average rate.   If events of two types are arriving independently of previous events (and each other) at constant average rates, then their combined count is *by definition* a Poisson random variable with a average rate of the sum of their average rates.

Because any given event will be of type $X$ at probability of $\lambda_x/(\lambda_x+\lambda_y)$, then when given that there are $w$ events of either type, therefore the distribution for the count of events of type $X$ will be...

> $$X\mid X+Y=w~\sim~\mathcal{Bin}(w, \lambda_x/(\lambda_x+\lambda_y))$$